# Capture image on google chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, charts

I am currently using the google chart API, all is running well
but then a specs came that the image should be captured,,on this i called the `getImageURI()`
function of the google chart API, Calling this function after the chart is ready. This came from the google: **Note: You should wait for the ready event, as shown in the examples on this page, to ensure that the chart has finished rendering.**

```
var my_div = document.getElementById('my_div');
var my_chart = new google.visualization.ChartType(chart_div);
var imgUri;
  google.visualization.events.addListener(my_chart, 'ready', function () {
  imgUri = chart.getImageURI();

  document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField1.ClientID%>").value = imgUri;
  });

my_chart.draw(data);
```

My HiddenField1 will be populated after the chart is already rendered, or simply speaking when the page is already done loading. This happens when I clicked a preview button.

However my specs indicated that HiddenField1 should be populated right after the print button is clicked, means it should have a value right before it finish rendering the asp page.

Ex current scenario :

Step 1: button preview is clicked --> the hidden field is populated with png string value.
Step 2: button print is clicked --> the hidden field has value so i can print png image.

Expected scenario :

button print is clicked --> on fly right before the page finish loading or the chart is ready, hidden field should already has a value so that i can print a png image.

I hope you can input on this, I read some of the articles on setTimeOut function on javascript, but I can't apply it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageVariable = document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField1.ClientID%>");
imageVariable.src = imgUri;
```